# Use another computer headphone/mic jack

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

So on my Gaming PC it's headphone and mic jack dont work, I was quoted to get them fixed for $100 which seems far too expensive. But I have another windows laptop which is next to me which has a working headphone + Mic jack. Is there anyway to stream my gamin PC audio to my laptops audio and at the same time stream back the microphone from that computer?

Comment: That's a really silly idea, especially for gaming. You don't want the latency even if you don't mind the hassle (presuming that it is possible). Just get a [USB sound card](http://us.creative.com/p/sound-blaster/sound-blaster-play-2).

Comment: The latency difference between the audio and video will give you a jarring and potentially uncomfortable gaming experience. Connected by LAN your latency for encoding, transport and decoding *might* be less than 40 to 50ms, but probably higher over WiFi. You will press a button, see a hit on the screen, then a brief moment later hear the sound of the hit. It might be a small length of time to you, but you will be able to tell that the audio is delayed.

Comment: I'm using Steam's Home Steaming service at the moment, because someone in a diferent forum suggested it, and it works almost perfectly. there is close to no delay I can recognise, the only thing is that it is also streaming the video which I dont need

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do sounds really funny.

It doesn't really answer the question in the title, but the best way to get this problem solved would be to get a PCI or USB Audio card and get going with it. These are extremely inexpensive and offer good sound to be fair.

As far as streaming from another PC is concerned, it is really not good for gaming, because you would have a large latency. There are a few software out there that claim to do this (I've tried and failed in this), but I can't say I recommend them.

See this question: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22921/stream-windows-audio-over-the-network